# How can I get a UWP GridView to scroll horizontally with the mouse wheel

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developping an application that needs a sort of timeline.

It can be very long. So I want to be able to scroll horizontally using mouse wheel or the bottom scrollbar, and also vertically using the right scrollbar.
I also need to be able to select items in the timeline, so I used a GridView with a Canvas inside the ItemsPanel.

It works well, except on one point : when I use the mouse wheel, the GridView scrolls vertically. I would like it to scroll horizontally instead.

The solution of disabling vertical scrolling is not an option, because I need to be able to scroll vertically using the right scrollbar.

The solution of using a panel with Orientation="Horizontal" is also not an option because I need a Canvas.

I know I can implement the horizontal scrolling by handling the PointerWheelChangedEvent and calling MouseWheelLeft and MouseWheelRight on the ScrollContentPresenter. But I couldn't find a way to disable the vertical scroll behavior built into the ScrollViewer...

Here is the XAML code for the GridView :

```
<GridView Background="White"
              Width="400"
              Height="200"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="1000"
                        Height="300" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.Items>
            <GridViewItem Background="Gray"
                          Content="Item 1"
                          Canvas.Left="100"
                          Canvas.Top="50" />
            <GridViewItem Background="Gray"
                          Content="Item 2"
                          Canvas.Left="300"
                          Canvas.Top="100" />
            <GridViewItem Background="Gray"
                          Content="Item 3"
                          Canvas.Left="600"
                          Canvas.Top="50" />
            <GridViewItem Background="Gray"
                          Content="Item 4"
                          Canvas.Left="600"
                          Canvas.Top="200" />
            <GridViewItem Background="Gray"
                          Content="Item 5"
                          Canvas.Left="700"
                          Canvas.Top="250" />
        </GridView.Items>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: You may be able to capture the PreviewMouseWheel event, and do the scrolling manually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewmousewheel?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Hi, UWP only has the `PointerWheelChanged` event, which means that it cannot be processed before vertical scrolling occurs. since UWP is mobile-first in design, there is very little horizontal scrolling. In the case of VerticalScrollMode != ScrollMode.Disabled, vertical scrolling cannot be intercepted. And if you really need this feature, you can initiate a feature request [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform).

Comment: Thanks @RichardZhang-MSFT for your answer. The feature request is here : https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/38565889-allow-a-gridview-to-scroll-horizontally-using-mous please vote for it !

Comment: Thank you for your support, Microsoft engineers will handle this request after receiving. :)